# c2dm receiver doesn't work when app has been killed

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In manifest in application tag I have:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyC2dmReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <!-- Receive the actual message -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category
            android:name="com.my.app" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Receive the registration id -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category
            android:name="com.my.app" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my receiving has sth like that

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
        handleRegistration(context, intent);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
    }
}
```

When my app is on or in background `onReceive` method is fired, but when I kill app using AdvancedTaskKiller `onRecived` stops receiving. Why?

Why Android doesn't start my receiver? Do I need sth in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

If you are on Android 3.1 or newer, it is because your application has been moved into the stopped state. This also occurs if the user force-stops you via the Settings application. Until the user manually launches your app again (e.g., taps on an icon in the launcher), none of your `BroadcastReceivers` will work.

Comment: There is no workaround? What happens when device was switched off, and then new c2dm comes, will it fire app?

Comment: @Mikoos: "There is no workaround?" -- no. The user has indicated they do not want your app to run. Hence, your app will not run. If you do not want this to happen, do not give users any reason to want to kill your app. "What happens when device was switched off, and then new c2dm comes, will it fire app?" -- if the device is turned off, nothing happens, any more than anything happens with a lamp that is turned off.

Comment: Ok after reebot it's reciving again. But how can I make work? Many people are just pressing killall apps every 10minutes (including me).

Comment: @Mikooos: "But how can I make work?" -- don't kill the app. "Many people are just pressing killall apps every 10minutes (including me)." -- so? If that's what they want to do, you do not have the right to stop them.

Comment: So I am having the same problem - everything works as advertised on older android devices, but the newer ones if the application is not running then the C2DM messages are not received.  Is this by design?  So many people clean the running apps these days, it seems like C2DM would never work.